# HDLC Frames - Octets/modulo 8 doubts

Tags: c, embedded, protocols, firmware

I am trying to implement the HDLC frame format type 3 and I have some doubts as regards Octets/Modulo 8 encoding of frames.

1. Firstly, Is the HDLC frame transmitted entirely in Octets?
2. What do they mean by **a frame is *'n'* Octet in length?** Please give an example.
3. I believe that Octet and Modulo is the same, so assuming that we have a frame **X** of one byte, what then do they mean by **the encoding of *X* shall be modulo 8**.

I am getting a little confused with all this, so i need more clarifications. Example and illustration will be of great help.

Thanks in Advance.

---

Thanks @clifford and @masoud. Your answer was really helpful. But I have to read this [Octet String: What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241223/octet-string-what-is-it) (though it sounds funny because it explained in a simple way), and I came back to read your comments, then I understood all you explained. All the same, wish me a happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, Is the HDLC frame transmitted entirely in Octets?

That simply means that the data length is a multiple of 8 bits. Yes it is.

> What do they mean by a frame is 'n' Octet in length?

Who is "they"? Cite your reference material.  An octet is simply a group of eight bits.  It is a less ambiguous term that byte (which can rarely be used refer to a machine word of length other than eight bits).  The term octet is widely used in telecommunications, and is also used in languages other than English to mean "byte" (when a byte is eight bits).

> I believe that Octet and Modulo

Not at all, *modulo* is a mathematical term, used here perhaps inaccurately to mean exactly divisible by (or an exact multiple of) eight.

> [...] what then do they mean by the encoding of X shall be modulo 8.[?]

Again who are "they"? If we can see where you are reading this in context, you may get a better explanation.

**Edit:**
I have not gone to the length of referencing ISO 3309 which is the standard defining HDLC frame structure, but the term "Modulo 8" in at least the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) is used only in the context of frame sequence numbers, where it simply means that a sequence number increments from 0 to 7, then restarts at 0 (i.e. it is the frame number modulo 8 - or the remainder of frame_num/8 or simple `frame_num % 8` in C code.  I wonder whether you are confusing terms - again a citation or extract would help.

Comment: My citation is the IEC62056-46.

Answer (score 4):

In HDLC every field length must be modulo 8 for example:

A frame of HDLC is like below:
`[FLAG(8bits)|ADDRESS(8bits)|CONTROL(8/16bits)|INFORMATION(n*8bits)|FCS(8bits)|FLAG(8bits)]`

each field is modulo 8, even length of INFORMATION must be modulo 8.

It means if you want to send a data with length of 1 bit, you must consume a byte(8 bits).

If you are looking for some HDLC frame sample, look at this link: [Click me!](http://www.dlms.com/faqanswers/questionsonthedlmscosemspecification/areexamplesforinformationexchangeavailable.php)
and read this: [Click me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control)

Comment: Thanks @Masoud, But I still cant place what you mean by ** If you want to send a data with Length of 1 bit, you must consume 1 byte**. To help, can you please explain using the opening Flag of the HDLC frame and maybe the frame type and length as below, illustrating using binary, Hexadecimal and the Octet/Modulo 8. 
**7E// HDLC frame opening flag
A00A// frame type and length**. Thanks once again!

Comment: `7E = (01111110) in binary` : it is a constant value to start and finish the frame, and you must put this value in begin and end of your frames. The second value(`A00A`) depends on your application. Binary, Hexadecimal and Octal are same in value, we use hexadecimal representation due to ease of reading for human.

Comment: **If you want to send a data with Length of 1 bit, you must consume 1 byte** means: For sending a bit of data, at least you have to use a byte.

Comment: Okay, I got that clarified. So Secondly, If i want to transmit a character **A** in Modulo 8. What will I be transmitting. I hope I am not mixing things up now. I just want more clarity. For example in the SNRM Frame 7EA00A00020023219318717E, apart from the Opening and closing flags, are all others in Modulo 8 like you said? if so, then where does **A** come from, because I believe Octet is from 0-7. Well, maybe if you show me some example of a frame of about 1 byte and how you encoded it to modulo 8, I believe that will help. Thanks once again.

Comment: Do you mean character `A` with ASCII code (1000001) in binary, or `A` that uses in hexadecimal representation? `7EA00A00020023219318717E` is hexadecimal value of frame not an ASCII string.

Comment: I mean character **A**. So if the frames are in HEX, then where is the Modulo 8 encoding.